# Distinguish two functions with the same name

Tags: cmake

I want to use multiple external CMake files in my project. Unfortunately two different files use the same CMake function name `foo`. I don't want to modify these external files.
Is there a way to call one specific function or will CMake error out? Would it help if one of the functions has a named parameter, i.e., `foo(a b c …)` and `foo(DESTINATION a b c …)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New function's definition **replaces** the previous one with the same name. So access to the previous function is lost.

If different functions (but with the same name) are used in different subprojects, you may try to build one subproject as `ExternalProject`, so function's collision wouldn't occure.

---

In CMake any function definitions contains the only piece of information for the caller - *minimal number of parameters* which should be passed to the function. By using this information it is impossible to resolve function's overloading, if it would be implemented.

Comment: It "is impossible" or "can be possible"?

Comment: In other words, a function's overloading **cannot be implemented** with current CMake language.